# Python expresses a number as a really large integer rather than a negative number

Tags: python, types, casting

Is there a way to force python to treat a number based upon its sign?

E.g. 0xFFFFFFFF = -1 instead of 4294967295?

Comment: Add a minus sign?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ctypes.c_int32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int32) for a signed 32 bit integer:

```py
import ctypes
wrapped = ctypes.c_int32(0xFFFFFFFF)
print(wrapped) # c_int(-1)
print(wrapped.value) # -1
```